# How to use libjs-jquery debian package in a project?

Tags: jquery, package, debian

I wish to use `libjs-jquery` package instead of attaching `jquery` file in my project.

After installing: `sudo apt-get install libjs-jquery`

how can I use it in my project?

**Note:** my project is sever side implemented in Python and it has web page access for panel. I wish to use `libjs-jquery` in that web page panel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `libjs-jquery` package contains `/usr/share/doc/libjs-jquery/README.Debian` which explains how to use the provided jQuery in your web site. Basically, all it takes is

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
src="/javascript/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

in your HTML header.

Alternatively, you can symlink `/usr/share/javascript/jquery/jquery.js` to the appropriate place in your own project.

In all instances `jquery.js` can be replaced with `jquery.min.js` or `jquery.lite.js` depending on your requirements.

Comment: As a side note, this works because javascript-common package installs [configuration files](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/javascript-common/filelist) in apache and lighttpd to make sure /javascript is served by the webserver and points to /usr/share/javascript. Not sure about nginx. This does not work anyway if using exotic servers such as Flask's embedded debug server for instance.

Comment: Also, those configuration files might not be enabled after installation, so e.g. for Apache one might need to use `a2enconf javascript-common`

Comment: @Karsten on Debian and derivatives that would probably be a bug; `javascript-common`’s `postinst` enables them for all supported web servers.